# Does drinking sparkling water lead to Osteoporosis?

Tags: medical-science, water

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does pop/soda pop cause Osteoporosis?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/does-pop-soda-pop-cause-osteoporosis)

According to several studies, drinking carbonated drinks elads to this.

> Osteoporosis
>   According to "Nelson Textbook of Pediatrics," there exists an association between lowered bone mass density in children and consuming carbonated beverages. These findings apply to both the diet and the regular carbonated cola formulations. Additionally, there is also positive correlation between bone fracture risk in children and carbonated beverage consumption. Carbonated drinks also contribute to bone loss in children. A decreased intake of milk in combination with an increased consumption of soda also contributes to an increase in cases of osteoporosis observed in pediatric medicine.

I drink an absurd amount of sparkling water and wondered if this is building myself up for many issues later in life.  I don't really enjoy tap water so compensate by drinking around 3 litres of sparkling a day, every day, for the past 10 years odd.  I was just told this will lead to calcium stripping of my bones.

Comment: I'm not sure the carbonated colas in the study include sparkling water as it does not have the sugars/phosphoric acid found in colas

Comment: I was specifically targetting this as a new post, as I was advised, specifically, that Sparkling water was an issue.  I wanted to move this away from Coke (other brands are available), as I need ot direct this specifically at Sparkling water.

Comment: @jos: If you look at the first answer in the linked question, you will read: "Soda (nor cola) does not cause osteoporosis." and soda *is* carbonated (or sparkling) water.